# Set part of the window title to bold

Tags: zk

I use ZK (just started learning), and I'd like to set some of the text from my modal window's title to bold.

Here is the code I use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">

<window apply="hidden-file-name" title="${msg:l('title')}"  width="390px" closable="true">

    <tablelayout columns="2">
        <!-- Some code -->
    </tablelayout>

</window>

</zk>
```

I have already divided `title` in my .properties file into `title` and `info`. I'd like the "info" part to appear in bold.

**Just in case, here's an example :**

Title : "This is my title"

Info : " and this is the info"

-> I want my modal window to have this title : "This is my title **and this is the info**".

**I found a dirty solution**, which is to set the "info" part as a caption, use `float: left;` to bring it to the left, and alter the css of the "title" part by setting a fixed width to remove the space appearing between the two parts, but as you can see, this is bad.. I'd like something clean.

Comment: The question is quite clear @NabilA., 'I want my modal window to have this title: "This is my title **and this is the info**". He wants *part* of the title to be bold, not all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Caption` to `Window` and the position should be by default 
[Title here]**[Caption Here]** 
so just put the info in the `Caption`s label and set it to bold.

To set different styles to the same label is as far as i know not
 
possible in zk directly.
Of course you can change it via java script, but this would imho
be overkill in your case.

### Edit

See [this](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/19v814u/2-Window-with-caption) example. You see that title and caption are both left.
So this is normal.

After I play around a bit, I found a solution. Look [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/19v814u/4-Window-with-caption).

Comment: I already did that. THe caption is aligned to the right. I want it to be on the left. When using float: left; it leaves a space between the title and the info. Only way to fix this is set a fixed width to the title. I don't want that.

Comment: Just change info and title and do not set any float. And as I mentioned above, you can not change the style from a label just for a part.

Comment: If I don't put the float, the caption  is aligned on the right. That's not what I want. I want the whole text aligned on the left.

Comment: ah ok I misunderstood you. This is strange I, this schould not happen. Try tu use plain text and not a loaded label. Is it still right?

Comment: I added a example, so you see that the standart is, that caption is directly behinde the title.

Comment: OK thanks, I remember trying that. It seems that if you use <caption><label... /></caption> it's totally different than when you use <caption label="" />. Now with this solution, my problem is the "-" between the title and the info. Any way to get rid of it ?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that if I apply style="font-weight: bold;" to the <caption label="" ... />, it also applies bold to the title..

Comment: I found a solution by changing the css `display` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try override the bind_ function to update the content of title after dom elements rendered by Client Side Programming,

e.g.,

```
<window border="normal" title="the bold title">
    <attribute w:name="bind_"><![CDATA[
        function (a, b, c) {
            this.$bind_(a, b, c);
            var cap = this.$n('cap');
            cap.innerHTML = cap.innerHTML.replace('bold', '<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span>');
        }
    ]]></attribute>
</window>
```

Ref:

[ZK Client Side Programming](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming)